# Headers not setting with redirect using node.js / Express

Tags: node.js, header, http-headers, express

I am relatively new to node.js, Express, and mobile development, and have run into a problem that I think has to do with sending headers with Express.

The user starts at the home page '/', not logged in, then clicks a button to go to the sign-in page.  When they submit their username and password to '/validate_signin', they should be redirected back to the home page, this time with the home page showing up differently because they are logged in.

The redirection worked like this:

```
res.redirect('/');
```

This works fine on my laptop, but on my mobile phone it redirects to '/', in its old state, presumably because of caching. If I refresh the page on the phone, '/' will show up as it should.

I found this post:
[How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Have tried to set headers in the following two ways (separately), but they don't seem to be sending:

```
res.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
res.header("Pragma", "no-cache");
res.header("Expires", 0);

res.writeHead(302, {
    "location": "/",
    "Cache-Control" : "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Expires": 0
});
```

Here are the headers that I am currently receiving:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
X-Powered-By: Express
Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2012 17:35:18 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Jul 2012 12:32:12 GMT
Etag: "3223-1342182732000"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Those headers would need to be written on the page you want not to cache (`/`), not the page where you're doing the redirect, right?

Comment: Correct.  Yeah, probably am setting them in the wrong place.  Going to look into this.

Comment: Your problem doesn't involve browser caching. For whatever reason, Express is sending out a 304 rather than an actual redirect, and the browser is responding appropriately (i.e. keeping the old version). It sounds like some kind of internal caching being done by Express; are you by any chance using express.static to serve the page in question?

Comment: @ebohlman As I look into the problem a bit more, as indicated by brandon-tilley, I see that '/signin/' page has the 302 header, and the '/' page has the 304 header.  Yes, I actually am using:     server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static/', {maxAge: -1})); ... any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using express.static to serve the home page? If so, what is it that makes the home page look different when the user's signed in? A cookie setting?

Comment: @ebohlman I'm checking if a user is signed in on that session, and if they are, displaying a different page than before login.  So it does use cookies.

Comment: Show the code that displays the home page.

Comment: @ebohlman var server = express.createServer();
    server.use(express.bodyParser());  // Post
    server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static/'));
    server.use(express.cookieParser());
    server.use(express.session({ secret: "..." }));

Comment: Hi, did you ever found how to solves this? I'm getting the same issue here :(

Answer (score 10):

I'd comment but I just joined today and don't have any reputation points.

If I understand it correctly, you're serving the page using express.static (so it's just a plain HTML page) but if the user is signed-in, you use express's router, am I correct?

I'm also guessing you put the mentioned code to set the headers in the homepage's route.

If that's the case, your issue isn't browser-caching, it occurs due to the nature of `connect` middlewares.

Middlewares execute in a chain, calling the next one when they're done, which means, if I assumed correctly, express.static is called prior to your router and it simply serve the static HTML page.

So your route is never executed because express.static won't call `next()` (for an obvious reason, the file exists).

Hope I assumed right.

---

**Edit:**

Looks like I assumed wrong. You did say it works fine on your laptop so it definitely looks like a client-side caching issue.

I'm still not sure how exactly you display a different homepage using express.static() or where you place the code you mentioned above, I'm going to give it a shot without seeing your code but it may be needed for me and others in order to help you out.

Those response headers should be set in the first response (when you visit the homepage), it has nothing to do with the redirect. Let's put the redirect part asides, for now.

I wrote a quick (express) example:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http')
    app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));

  /*
  * Here's where I set the headers, make sure it's above `express.static()`.
  * 
  * Note: You can safely ignore the rest of the code, (it's pretty much "stock").
  */
  app.use(function noCachePlease(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url === '/') {
      res.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
      res.header("Pragma", "no-cache");
      res.header("Expires", 0);
    }

    next();
  });

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function() {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

This code instructs my browser not to cache the page.

The response headers I get **without** the `noCachePlease` middleware:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Cache-Control   public, max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  5
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Fri, 20 Jul 2012 19:25:38 GMT
Etag    "5-1342811956000"
Last-Modified   Fri, 20 Jul 2012 19:19:16 GMT
X-Powered-By    Express
```

The response headers I get **with** the `noCachePlease` middleware:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  5
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Fri, 20 Jul 2012 19:26:08 GMT
Etag    "5-1342811956000"
Expires 0
Last-Modified   Fri, 20 Jul 2012 19:19:16 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
X-Powered-By    Express
```

So as you can see, it works but you could run this code yourself.

If you want to run it, you'll need to have `express` under `node_modules` or installed globally (with the `-g` flag).

Comment: Thanks for the answer/comment.  Actually, I use express.static for both cases.  When the page loads (rather than just being taken from the cache), it should do a call to '/issignedin/' via ajax, and based on that, javascript will load the appropriate page layout.  Here you can see the site: http://184.73.213.206:8080/

Comment: @Nathan My assumption was incorrect. I'm pretty sure my updated answer (with a working example) would be helpful. If it's still not it, maybe you should post some relevant parts of your code (probably middlewares and routes).

Comment: Thank you for the great example.  I thought it would work, but I'm getting the same response, even after clearning my browser's cache and trying again.  I'll look into this a bit more, and then post my code.  Thanks again.